# Scrape data from all the pages in a website

Tags: python, web-scraping

[This is the website](https://www.rfpmart.in/)
I want all the text from this website saved as a csv file with the following column names

**Description | Posted Date | Expiry Date**

```
import requests as rq    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.rfpmart.in/"
response  = rq.get(url)
if response.status_code == 200:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
   div_text = soup.find('div',{'id':'home'}).text
```

I am a beginner a I have done this far.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add what u have tried so far, to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start. now you need to iterate through the specific tags with that content within the first `<div>` tags you are pulling, followed by constructing the dataframe.

**Code:**

```
import requests as rq    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.rfpmart.in/" 
response  = rq.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
endPage = int(soup.find('p',{'class':'counter'}).text.split()[-1])

desc = []
post = []
exp = []
urls = []

for page in range(1,endPage+1):
    print ('Aquiring page: %s'%page)
    url = "https://www.rfpmart.in/home-%s.html" %page
    response  = rq.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
       div = soup.find('div',{'id':'home'})

       items = div.find_all('li')
       for each in items:
           desc.append(each.find('div', {'class':'description-category'}).text.strip())
           post.append(each.find('span',{'class':'post-date'}).text.strip())
           exp.append(each.find('span',{'class':'expiry-date'}).text.strip())
           urls.append(each.find('a')['href'])

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(desc, post, exp, urls)), 
               columns =['Description','Posted Date','Expiry Date', 'URL'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
                                          Description  ...               Expiry Date
0   EXTRA-8365-USA (Oakland, California) - Perinat...  ...  Wednesday, 15 July, 2020
1   EXTRA-8364-USA (Santa Cruz, California) - Prof...  ...   Thursday, 25 June, 2020
2   SW-33969-USA (California) - Java Software Deve...  ...  Wednesday, 10 June, 2020
3   SW-33968-USA (California) - Electronic Agenda ...  ...     Monday, 15 June, 2020
4   WRT-1475-USA (Beebe, Arkansas) - Title III Gra...  ...     Monday, 15 June, 2020
5   DE-3174-USA (California) - Paper to Digital Do...  ...    Thursday, 9 July, 2020
6   TRANSLATION-3588-USA (California) - Translatio...  ...     Tuesday, 9 June, 2020
7   ACCT-9172-USA (San Angelo, Texas) - Audit Serv...  ...     Friday, 12 June, 2020
8   ACCT-9173-USA (Texas) - Audit Services for Tax...  ...      Monday, 1 June, 2020
9   ESTATE-3249-USA (San Antonio, Texas) - Real Es...  ...   Thursday, 25 June, 2020
10  SW-33980-USA (New Jersey) - Document Managemen...  ...    Thursday, 28 May, 2020
11  FOOD-5243-USA (Garden City, New York) - Food S...  ...   Thursday, 11 June, 2020
12  EXTRA-8369-USA (Camden, New Jersey) - Port Pla...  ...     Friday, 19 June, 2020
13  TRANSPORT-3411- USA (Aztec, New Mexico) - Inma...  ...    Thursday, 4 June, 2020
14  CSE-7613-USA (Lincoln, Nebraska) - Event Secur...  ...   Thursday, 11 June, 2020
15  TRANSPORT-3410-USA (Bedford, Texas) - Third Pa...  ...    Tuesday, 16 June, 2020
16  ITES-2658-USA (Salem, New Jersey) - Informatio...  ...     Friday, 12 June, 2020
17  MRB-16554-USA (North Carolina) - Paid Media Su...  ...     Friday, 19 June, 2020
18  MB-4214-USA (New York) - Claims Auditor Servic...  ...     Tuesday, 9 June, 2020
19  TRANS-1529-USA (New York) - Court Reporting an...  ...   Thursday, 18 June, 2020
20  CSE-7612-USA (Frederick, Maryland) - Security ...  ...   Thursday, 18 June, 2020
21  CSE-7611-USA (Fall River, Massachusetts) - Vid...  ...   Thursday, 11 June, 2020
22  SW-33960-USA (North Carolina) - Communications...  ...     Friday, 26 June, 2020
23  SW-33958-USA (Colorado) - Cloud Based Human Re...  ...    Tuesday, 30 June, 2020
24  SURG-1921-USA (Louisiana) - N95 Mask Supplies-...  ...   Wednesday, 27 May, 2020
25  MRB-16555-USA (Kentucky) - Legislative Video P...  ...     Tuesday, 2 June, 2020
26  SW-33959-USA (North Carolina) - Transit Mobile...  ...     Friday, 12 June, 2020
27  SW-33975-USA (Massachusetts) - Comprehensive S...  ...     Friday, 12 June, 2020
28  MB-4215-USA (Massachusetts) - Ambulance Billin...  ...   Thursday, 11 June, 2020
29  NET-3016-USA (Leander, Texas) - Signal Communi...  ...    Thursday, 4 June, 2020
..                                                ...  ...                       ...
70  ACCT-9168-Canada (Alberta) - Occupational Heal...  ...  Wednesday, 10 June, 2020
71  ACCT-9167-USA (Atlanta, Georgia) - Audit Servi...  ...   Thursday, 25 June, 2020
72  STAFF-4366-USA (Houston, Texas) - RFI for Mobi...  ...    Thursday, 28 May, 2020
73  MEDI-1919-USA (Macon, Georgia) - Medical Clini...  ...   Thursday, 25 June, 2020
74  CSE-7607-USA (Washington, DC) - RFI for Securi...  ...    Saturday, 6 June, 2020
75  STAFF-4367-USA (Calhoun, Georgia) - Nursing Se...  ...     Monday, 22 June, 2020
76  CR-0991-USA (Saint Paul, Minnesota) - Court Re...  ...     Tuesday, 2 June, 2020
77  SW-33956-USA (Washington) - Asset Tracking Sof...  ...      Friday, 29 May, 2020
78  SW-33957-USA (Georgia) - Automated Weather Obs...  ...     Friday, 26 June, 2020
79  SW-33955-USA (Texas) - Moodle Programming Serv...  ...    Thursday, 4 June, 2020
80  MRB-16551-USA (Texas) - Comprehensive Integrat...  ...    Thursday, 28 May, 2020
81  ITES-2656-USA (Fort Wayne, Indiana) - RFI for ...  ...      Monday, 8 June, 2020
82  CSE-7608-USA (Hawaii) - Library Rules Enforcem...  ...      Friday, 5 June, 2020
83  DRA-1532-USA (Hawaii) - Arrest Charge Disposit...  ...  Wednesday, 10 June, 2020
84  MRB-16553-USA (Michigan) - Outreach and Affirm...  ...    Tuesday, 16 June, 2020
85  FOOD-5240-USA (Washington, DC.) - Inmate Food ...  ...  Wednesday, 17 June, 2020
86  SW-33970-USA (Washington, DC.) - ADA Compliant...  ...      Friday, 29 May, 2020
87  PM-12591-USA (Philadelphia, Pennsylvania) - Pr...  ...      Monday, 1 June, 2020
88  PM-12590-USA (Washington, DC.) - Printing Serv...  ...      Monday, 1 June, 2020
89  EXTRA-8363-USA (Fort Lauderdale, Florida) - Ma...  ...     Monday, 22 June, 2020
90  SW-33963-USA (Florida) - Information Managemen...  ...     Monday, 15 June, 2020
91  EXTRA-8362-USA (Sarasota, Florida) - American ...  ...  Wednesday, 17 June, 2020
92  SW-33954-USA (Wisconsin) - RFI for Application...  ...     Tuesday, 12 May, 2020
93  LEGAL-4987-USA (Charleston, West Virginia) - O...  ...  Wednesday, 24 June, 2020
94  PM-12588-USA (Encinitas, California) - Managed...  ...  Wednesday, 10 June, 2020
95  ESTATE-3246-USA (Charlotte, North Carolina) - ...  ...    Tuesday, 16 June, 2020
96  DISPOS-3793-USA (Fortana, California) -Removal...  ...    Thursday, 4 June, 2020
97  SW-33952-USA (New York) - GPS Tracking System-...  ...   Thursday, 11 June, 2020
98  SW-33953-Canada (Ontario) - VMware Support Ser...  ...    Thursday, 4 June, 2020
99  SW-33951- USA (South Carolina) - Professional ...  ...   Thursday, 25 June, 2020

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. But I want the data from all the 1800 pages available. The above code only collects the first 100 records. Please help.

Comment: @BibinBinny, just have to iterate through the pages. see edit above

Comment: Thanks a lot. And one more thing. Can I get the urls that each description is having too..